# Example of a locally Lipschitz function such that $f'(x)$ is not bounded by $c(1+(f(x))^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Do you know an example of a locally Lipschitz function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ such that there is not a constant $c$ such that
$$|f'(x)| \leq  c(1+(f(x))^2)$$
almost everywhere? I know that $f(x)$ cannot be a polynomial or $\sqrt{x}$

Comment: The solution of the differential equation $f' = 1 + f^3$ should work?

Comment: or this https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=f%27+%3D+Divide%5B1%2CPower%5Bf%2C4%5D%5D+%2B+Power%5Bf%2C4%5D but it's not defined on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace: Unless I am mistaken, $f' = 1 + f^3$ does not have a solution on all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @MartinR Yes that's what I wrote (but I should have done it twice)

Comment: I could also think of a high periodic sine, but this would not be true on $\mathbb{R}$ in itself. Does your function have to be differentiable everywhere or not? Otherwise just draw a very sharp saw teeth signal that gets sharper and sharper

Comment: The function $f$ must be differentiable almost everywhere

Comment: What about $f(x) = \sin(x^2)$?

Comment: @MartinR sometimes $f'$ goes through $0$ though the formulation is tricky

Comment: The function $f(x)=\sin(x^2)$ should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help! $\sin(x^2)$ works.

Comment: If you are after an unbounded function $g(x)=x+\sin(x^4).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x) = \sin(x^2)$ is an example. It is locally Lipschitz because the derivative is continuous, and
$$
 \frac{|f'(x)|}{1+f(x)^2} = \frac{2 |x \cos(x^2)|}{1+\sin^2(x^2)}
$$
is not bounded because
$$
 \frac{|f'(x)|}{1+f(x)^2} \ge \frac{|x|}{1+3/4}
$$
on all intervals where $\cos(x^2) > 1/2$.